# How can I count the total number of document indexed by my oracle.text index?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I know I can use `ctx_query.count_hits` to count the number of document matching a query,
and similarly, I can use

```
count(*) where CONTAINS(...)
```

But these are only options if I actually have a query. Those functions throw an exception if I pass an empty string as a query (thanks oracle...). So,

> Is there a way to count the total number of document indexed by my
>   oracle.text index?

Comment: Never used text indexes, but it sounds like you just want a simple `count(*)` of the table where the indexed field `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: The index is built using a user store that filters and joins several tables, not just 1 table. That mean that I would need to reproduce the index building logic in a count query, which does not make sense.